Simplicial Homology Groups of $\mathbb{R}P(2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{F}_2$
In my introductory algebraic topology class, my professor has set an exercise based on the following simplicial complex: 
This is the simplicial complex $\mathbb{R}P(2)$ which triangulates the real projective plane. This complex has vertex set $V_X=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and 2-simplicies $$\sigma^2=\{[0,2,3],[0,1,3],[2,3,5],[3,4,5],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[0,2,4],[0,4,5],[0,1,5]\}$$ along with all 1-simplicies and 0-simplicies implied by these 2-simplicies.
Let $\mathbb{F}_2$ be the field with two elements $\{0,1\}$ and let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rational field.
The exercise asks me to first calculate $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2),\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2),\mathbb{Q})$ by direct matrix calculations. The exercise then asks that I calculate $H_1(\mathbb{R}P(2),\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $H_1(\mathbb{R}P(2),\mathbb{Q})$ without using matrix calculations given the 2nd homology groups and using that $\mathbb{R}P(2)$ is a connected complex.
I'm still learning the basics of simplicial homology meaning that I'm having some trouble with the calculation and am not sure how to locate the error.

The 2nd homology groups are $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2))=\text{ker }\partial_2/\text{Im }\partial_3$. Since there are no 3-simplicies, this is just $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2))=\text{ker }\partial_2$.
To calculate these for the two fields, I first label the 2-simplicies and 1-simplicies as follows, $$\begin{align*}&E_1=[0,2,3],E_2=[0,1,3],E_3=[2,3,5],E_4=[3,4,5],\\ &E_5=[1,3,4],E_6=[1,2,4],E_7=[1,2,5],E_8=[0,2,4],\\ &E_9=[0,4,5],E_{10}=[0,1,5] \end{align*}$$ and $$\begin{align*}& e_1=[0,2],e_2=[2,3],e_3=[0,3],e_4=[0,1],\\ &e_5=[1,3],e_6=[1,2],e_7=[2,4],e_8=[1,4],\\ &e_9=[3,4],e_{10}=[3,5],e_{11}=[2,5],e_{12}=[1,5] \\ &e_{13}=[0,4],e_{14}=[0,5], e_{15}=[4,5] \end{align*}$$
With this ordering of the bases, I find that the matrix representing the second boundary map $\partial_2:C_2(\mathbb{R}P(2))\to C_1(\mathbb{R}P(2))$ is the $15\times 10$ matrix below $$\partial_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Over $\mathbb{Q}$, since both $1$ and $-1$ are rational, this is the transformation. Row reduction gives that $\text{rnk }\delta_2=10$. Therefore, $\text{dim ker }\partial_2=0$. Whence $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{Q})=0$.
Over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $-1$ is identified with $1$, so the $\partial_2$ transform can be written as $$\partial_2^{\mathbb{F}_2}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ By row reduction I get that $\text{rnk }\partial_2^{\mathbb{F}_2}=10$ so again $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{F}_2)=0$. This is not correct as Example 2.50 from Hatcher says that $H_k(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{F}_2)\approx \mathbb{F}_2$ for $0\leq k \leq 2$. Where am I making an error?
Ignoring this issue, assuming I know $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{Q})$ and $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{F}_2)$, I continue with the exercise. Since $\mathbb{R}P(2)$ is connected, $H_0(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{Q})\approx \mathbb{Q}$ and $H_0(\mathbb{R}P(2);\mathbb{F}_2)\approx \mathbb{F}_2$. I now divide $\mathbb{R}P(2)$ into the two subcomplexes $X_+$ and $X_-$ where $X_+$ has 2-simplicies $$\sigma_+^2=\{[0,2,3],[0,1,3],[0,2,4],[0,4,5],[0,1,5]\}$$ and the 1 and 0-simplicies implied by these. On the other hand, $X_-$ has 2-simplicies $$\sigma_-^2=\{[2,3,5],[3,4,5],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,5]\}$$ and the 1 and 0-simplicies implied by these.
The complex $X_+$ is a cone with star point $0$, so $H_k(X_+)$ is isomorphic to the underlying field if $k=0$ and is $0$ for all $k\geq 1$.
The complex $X_-$ has a 0th homology group which is isomorphic to the underlying field as it is connected. Additionally, I think that the first homology group of $X_-$ is $0$, but I can't think of a quick way to show this with the methods I know.
Given these homologies, consider the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence $$H_1(X_+)\oplus H_1(X_-)\to H_1(\mathbb{R}P(2))\to H_0(X_+\cap X_-)\to H_0(X_+)\oplus H_0(X_-)\to H_0(\mathbb{R}P(2))\to 0 $$ Given previous computations this gives the exact sequence (with $\mathbb{K}$ the underlying field) $$0\to H_1(\mathbb{R}P(2)) \to \mathbb{K}\to \mathbb{K}\oplus \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{K}\to 0$$ Whiteheads lemma then gives $H_1(X)=0$ irrespective of the underlying field. Again this is at odds with Hatcher's example 2.50. Where have I gone wrong? I presume that knowing $H_2(\mathbb{R}P(2))$ and $H_0(\mathbb{R}P(2))$ will help with calculating $H_1(\mathbb{R}P(2))$ by a similar Mayer-Vietoris sequence, but I am not sure what I've gotten confused.
The only methods of homology calculation we've done in the course so far are direct matrix calculations, Mayer-Vietoris sequences, and the relation between the homology groups of the simplicial complex and it's n-skeletons, so if there is a simple way to calculate the homology using these that would be ideal.

Someone has pointed out the issue with your computation. But I want to tell you that all these computation would be easy if you had taken a simpler simplicial complex structure of $\mathbb{R} P^2$ (look hatcher). Also, if you have already calculated the integral homology groups there is a way to get the homology groups for any $\mathbb{Z}$-module via Universal coefficient theorem. You will learn about it later. I just wanted to tell you there is simpler way to calculate the homology group but the way you proceeded is valid.

@TrishanMondal: This is the simplest simplicial complex structure on $\mathbb{R}P^2$. Hatcher uses $\Delta$-complexes to get something smaller, but those are not the same as simplicial complexes.

The rank of the matrix for $\partial_2^{\mathbb{F}_2}$ should be 9, not 10, at least when I do the calculation. You can check this with Sage if you want:
sage: RP2 = simplicial_complexes.RealProjectivePlane()
sage: C = RP2.chain_complex()
sage: C.differential(2).change_ring(GF(2)).rank()
9

I guess this might be more convincing if I made sure to use your simplicial complex structure:
sage: K = SimplicialComplex([[0,2,3],[0,1,3],[2,3,5],[3,4,5],[1,3,4],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[0,2,4],[0,4,5],[0,1,5]])
sage: C = K.chain_complex()
sage: C.differential(2).change_ring(GF(2)).rank()
9

For the second part, the Euler characteristic seems like a good tool and perhaps one you've seen by now. You can calculate the Euler characteristic for the projective plane using its simplicial complex description — it's $1$ — and then when working over a field, once you know all of the homology groups but one, you can compute the last one from the Euler characteristic.

Thank you for your answer! To be clear, are you saying that I have made a mistake with the row reduction of $\partial_2^{\mathbb{F}_2}$? Or that my matrix for $\partial_2^{\mathbb{F}_2}$ is incorrect? I know that the rank should be 9 to give Hatcher’s formulae, but I can’t tell where I’ve gone wrong.

Also, I had no idea that we could use the Euler characteristic to calculate the Betti numbers like that. That’s very cool, thank you!

According to Sage, your matrix has rank 9. I haven't checked that it is the correct matrix for $\partial_2$ — Sage uses a different ordering on the edges, so its matrix is different — but yours looks okay at a glance: two nonzero entries in each row (because each edge appears in the boundary of two faces), three nonzero entries in each column (since each face has three boundary edges).

I found my mistake in the row reduction and have managed to get the right answer out after redoing the subcomplex splits and Mayer-Vietoris sequences, thank you!
